# How to combine the columns of two tables that don't have any column in common?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Car` :

| Brand | Miles |
| --- | --- |
| Some brand | 120 |
| Another brand | 300 |

And `NewNumberPlate` :

| NumberPlate |
| --- |
| 361 2360 |
| 418 2711 |

These two tables always have the same number of rows. I would like to find a way to combine them, in a way to assign a new and unique numberplate to each car like below :

| Brand | Miles | NumberPlate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some brand | 120 | 361 2360 |
| Another brand | 300 | 418 2711 |

I have tried the following :

```
SELECT Car.Brand, Car.Miles, NewNumberPlate.NumberPlate INTO #newCars FROM Car, NewNumberPlate;
```

But the result I'm getting is the following :

| Brand | Miles | NumberPlate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some brand | 120 | 361 2360 |
| Another brand | 300 | 361 2360 |
| Some brand | 120 | 418 2711 |
| Another brand | 300 | 418 2711 |

Which does not work since I want the number plates to be unique. Any advice ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the ordering, unless a column specifies that.  But you can use `row_number()` to generate a key for joining:

```
select c.brand, c.miles, nn.NumberPlate
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from car c
     ) c join
     (select nn.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from NewNumberPlate nn
     ) nn
     on nn.seqnum = c.seqnum
```